# Create Setup and have database package inside it

Tags: c#, winforms, ms-access, windows-installer

I want to create a setup in my program (windows forms), I already could make a setup in my program (windows forms), but once I run, the program did not recognized, because my program is connected to the database. How do I create setup along with the database file inside the setup? So, when the setup is finished installing, the database which is saved in the certain folder, will be automatically placed in the target machine along with the application.

So, the application could used by user, because my application is connected to the database, without database, the application became useless.

But, how do I do that?

And when the application already published, and let's say I want to update the application (because I correct some bugs in the program). And when user open the program, it will ask to update to latest version. How do I also do that?

Could you guys help me?

Comment: Where you want to copy your access database during the installation ? To same installation location where your dlls will be copied ?

Comment: "connected to the database" which db?

Comment: @7-isnotbad: access database. ACCDB file.

Comment: @AccessDenied: yeah, it also can. Because i just want to run the program properly when the installation has completed.

Comment: how do you link dB, i mean your connection string's path attrib

Comment: `@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=..\db1.accdb";` , i am sorry if i posted wrongly, because i didn't clear understand what's your mean about

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow the steps gieven below, This will copy the access database to the installation path during installation.

1. Select your Installation project in the solution and then select `File System Editor` 
   [image: File System Editor]
2. Select the `Application Folder` under `File System on Target Machine` window. This will display all the assemblies and other files which will be copied to the installation path during the application deployment.

[image]

3. Right click in the middle panel (Where assemblies are listed) go to `Add` > `File` option which will open FileBrowserDialog and select the Access Database you want to package with the MSI.

[image]